# I want the type field from my STI model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, sti

I have a `User` model with an underlying `type` column that works as expected to implement Single Table Inheritance for child models `Teacher` and `Student` and so on.

I have a corresponding Rails Controller that calls `User.find` to pull individual records and again, STI is working out great. I'm getting properly typed model objects with the correct data in them.

But the `type` field itself is being excluded from the values extracted from my database rows. I would like that to be included in the results of `User.find` so my data looks something like:

```
{ id: 3, name: "Jane Doe", type: "Student" },
{ id: 7, name: "Jane Clark", type: "Teacher" }
```

I get why this isn't the default: most of the time the class or type of the actual object is the best way to communicate what kind of `User` you're looking at. But for my purposes, the type information is being lost in the JSON translation and I'd rather have it be sent in this literal form as I'm using it directly in the consumer application.

Therefore my question is: What is keeping the `type` field out of the output from `User.find`? What can I do to override that, ideally in a way that makes `type` appear to be just another ordinary data field?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround that is okay for right now.

The workaround is to stash the literal type by name, or whatever other type-specific information you want to pass along, in a public attribute in all the child models. E.g.,

```
def classProperty
  'Student'
end
```

For my purposes, it is good enough to retrieve this information in the calling controller and use ordinary Ruby data handling code to insert it in the JSONized response.

I'm still curious, however, about the mechanism by which the `type` column isn't showing up in my models and how it might be overcome in cases like this one.